# How to have permanent workspaces than dynamically creating

Tags: 20.04

I want to have 8 workspaces on my pc.

I have some windows which i want to move them to the 8th workspace.

How to remove the automatic creation of workspaces by ubuntu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `gnome-tweaks` you can choose to have a static number of Workspaces.

You can install it with:

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
```

If you need shortcuts to move windows between Workspaces, check out the `Keyboard Shortcuts` on gnome settings.

Comment: This configuration made it to the official settings in 22.04.